# selecting only working days from NSDate in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

My concern is..if am having text field with start date.when i am selecting date from calendar with day of Friday..then i want to skip weekend days saturday and sunday in enddate text field...i tried like this

```
NSString *strCurrentDate;
NSString *strNewDate;

NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

NSDateFormatter *df =[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
[df setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

strCurrentDate = [df stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"Current Date and Time: %@",strCurrentDate);

int hoursToAdd = roundedUp;

NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setDay:hoursToAdd];

NSDate *newDate= [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:date options:0];

[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
[df setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

strNewDate = [df stringFromDate:newDate];

NSLog(@"New Date and Time: %@",strNewDate);

while ([strNewDate compare:strCurrentDate] == NSOrderedAscending)
{
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:strNewDate];

    if (dateComponents.weekday == friday)
    {
        count =  count+2;
        NSLog(@"count = %d", count);
        NSDateComponents *oneDay = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        [oneDay setDay:2];
        NSString *endDate = [strNewDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:2*60*60*24];
        // [oneDay setDay:2];
    }
}
```

But I am not getting only week days… so can any one do the needful… thank u in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

To get the next working day from now use the method `isDateInWeekend` of `NSCalendar`

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
// Strip the time portion of the date
NSDate *date = [calendar startOfDayForDate:[NSDate date]];
do {
  // add 1 day until the result is not in a weekend
  date = [calendar dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value:1 toDate:date options:NSCalendarMatchNextTime];
} while (![calendar isDateInWeekend:date]);
NSLog(@"Next Workday: %@", date);
```